# How not to block the code with AXIOS.all error?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm working on a dashboard that makes several calls (3) to an API. In order to synthesize the code i used the AXIOS library with the AXIOS.all fonction.

- call No1 & 2: we query a table of data
- call No3: Count

This code consults the profile of a user and its data. Some users have data and some don't.
The calls work when the user has data and return a 404 error when the user doesn't.

In practice: when one of the calls fails to return data (error) then all the code is blocked.I imagine that it is the consequence of AXIOS.ALL..

So I had the following idea:

Create a first request that will verify a specific data on the API and set up a condition with if and else: if I receive an error then displays the following message in the div `<div>message</div>` of the body. Otherwise you can run all queries.

```
const AccountTab = () => {
  const [datalist, setDatalist] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState();
  const [infoscount, setInfoscount] = useState([]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const resultdata = await axios.get(getData(address));
      const resultcount = await axios.get(countData(address));
      const resultstuffcount = await axios.get(InfosStuff(address));

      axios.all([resultdata, resultcount, resultstuffcount]).then(
        axios.spread((...allData) => {
          const allData = allData[0].data; /* array */
          const allDataCount = allData[1].data; /* count */
          const allDataStuffCount = allData[2].data.count;
          /* We get an array but we retrieve the row 'count' -> count*/

          setDatalist(allData);
          setCount(allDataCount);
          setInfoscount(allDataStuffCount);
        })
      );
    };

    if (mounted.current) {
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return ()
};
```